# How do I launch a flow when a new item is posted on SharePoint?

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-flow

How do I launch a flow when a new item is posted on SharePoint?

I want to write a flow such that when someone posts an article on SharePoint, a predetermined set of persons are emailed that it has been done.   Can someone give me some advice on how to accomplish this?  I think the solution should be direct and obvious to those well-versed in Microsoft Automation.    I thought I would ask around.  I have some experience experimenting with Flows and Microsoft Automate.  So I think I can follow directions.  I think it would be best to pose this question and then look into educating myself on my own whilst a response is being made from my casting a proverbial net.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of predefined templates provided by both Microsoft and the community that should get you started.

Maybe this is what you are looking for? [Send a customized email when a new SharePoint list item is added](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/2bd714484de84d1391cb288208b9f609/send-a-customized-email-when-a-new-sharepoint-list-item-is-added/)

[Power Automate Templates](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/)

PowerAutomate's SharePoint connectors also have a trigger when a new item is created and/or modified that you can use in a custom developed flow.

[Microsoft SharePoint Connector in Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers)